# Fusioning check values in bounds

Tags: quaternions

I am fusioning data from Acc Gyro and Magn and i have the quaternions and they are looking good and accurate in OpenGL.

What i want is that the user can define max and min rotation for each axis else a vibration maybe will be happen.

Should i convert to Euler and have a degree to check if each of three values is in the bounds? I have already done that but Gimbal lock messes things up. But i want to be as user friendly as possible.

If i cant do that with Euler angles is there an other way to define a max and min quaternion maybe?

Example:

The user defines x:10 y:10 z:10 and if the calibrated values are:

```
if(x>= calX+x || x<=calX - x) {//and so on....
    //vivbrate
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Gimbal lock messes things up"? Are your axes relative to the body or a global reference frame?

Comment: When i convert quaternions to euler if an axe is 90 degrees i get gimbal and the other two axes show wrong values. I can really answer your question.